# Ways to keep a group of objects shared

Tags: objective-c

I'm fairly new to objective-c.
I'm trying to develop mostly experimental projects for a future development of a game app.

I would like to have suggestions on what I should use for the following purpose.

I'm trying to keep a group of objects somewhere (lets say something like an Array) in objective-c. I want that group  of objects to be available everywhere in my application (different functions etc.) That group of objects has to be edit ready so NSArray (I guess) is out of the question? must be.

I'm struggling with concepts and still looking for the right way to do such a thing, tried to force some global arrays but I think that wasn't good practice.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks. (Please be kind enough to provide some further explanation on why I should use this -your suggestion- instead of something else. In that way you will help me grasp the idea better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a group of objects that needs to be shared throughout the entire application, and you want to shy away from global variables, then I think you have one good option:

By creating and storing the collection (which should be an `NSMutableArray`, an editable version of `NSArray`) in your application delegate, it can be accessible everywhere:

```
//MyAppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *_editableArray;

//MyAppDelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    _editableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Add objects if you'd like
}
```

And then you can access it anywhere, like so:

```
// In other classes
((CastToYourAppDelegateClass *)[NSApp delegate]).editableArray;
```

**Keep in mind** that if you're going to be accessing/editing this array on any background thread (or using GCD) then you'll have to ensure that the access is properly synchronized. (Are you planning on doing so?)

Comment: wouldnt it be somehow better practice if i made a (lets say) world class, then make a subclass called enemies, and store all my enemie objects inside a NSMutableArray in the world class?
But im having doubts on how to use the NSMutableArray in my world class across different game states. For instance im thinking of an Init() function creating those objects, and a mainGameLoop() function handling the looping. now should i pass my world class from init() function to mainGameLoop in order to have access to it? im missing the point

Comment: Yea, absolutely, that sounds like a much better plan. But we don't know what your program does or how it works, so unless we've seen your code, we're not going to be able to provide you with suggestions or improvements beyond the scope of the information you provided in your original question.

Comment: woh, that was a fast responce. Anyways im short on code atm cause im still trying to get the idea down, then deploy code. Btw had to edit my first responce, thnx for all the help

Comment: Again, without seeing any code, we really can't help with code-specific issues. You can pass the variables between functions, or you can scope the functions so that the variables are accessible to them both. It's up to you. Best to start one way, and if you realize it isn't what you want, chalk it up to a lesson learned and go the other route.

Comment: thnx craig, you provided plenty usefull information, i think i can start from there. hehe cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to implement Singleton pattern for your shared object, that will have NSMutableArray as one of it's properties?